# Why does my code not work in this specific situation ? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to solve this specific CSES exercise and in the 9 and 10 test my code doesn't give back the right number, and I don't know why.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d12Bs.png)

Here is the link of the exercise : https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1069

Here is my code (Python 3):

```
count = 1
s = 1
longest_count = 1
input = input()

characters = []
for char in input :
    characters.append(char)

x = len(characters)

n = 0

while n < x - 1 :
    if characters[n] == characters[n+1]:
        count = count + 1
    elif s < count :

        s = count
        count = 1

    n = n + 1
    
if count < s : 
    print(s)
else : 
    print(count)
```

I have tried a lot of things but nothing worked for me, here is the screenshot of my code output and the right output : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwlnd.png)

Comment: The problem is that you only reset `count` if you have found a new maximum.  If the current sequence is shorter than the maximum, your counter will just keep going and going.

Comment: You aren't really asking for alternatives, but if you want to dive it, this problem can be done in a single line with `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @Mark -- I'd like to see that example.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think it's just this: `max(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(some_string))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the "count = 1" every time the sequence changes.  That means the else needs to be a bit more complicated:

```
for n in range(x-1):
    if characters[n] == characters[n+1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        if s < count:
            s = count
        count = 1
```

Alternatively:

```
    else:
        s = max(s, count)
        count = 1

print(max(s,count))
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, you are a good man